# Issue with foreground and background in FCM and flutter (Node Js backend)

Tags: android, ios, node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Dependency Used :**

```dart
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.1
flutter_local_notifications: ^6.0.0
firebase_core: ^1.2.1
firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
```

**Issue**

**case 1:**
When App is running in the background but not terminated or Forced Stopped its not triggering the method `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {}` instead it triggers `Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage? message) async {}`

**case 2:**
When App is in Terminated state for forced stopped, When received the notification its not triggering the `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {});` -> message is `null` ??

**Source Code:**

```dart
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Back ground method called");
}

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}


//Inside the Main Class//
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

     FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      print("Get Initial method called");

       Flutter toast.showToast(
            msg: message!.data,
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors .white,
            fontSize: 16.0); 
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
     print("On Message Listener is called");
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      print("on Message Opened is called");
    });
}
```

**Node Js Code**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("xxxx Path of the json file xxxx");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

app.post('/notification',(req, res)=>{
    var registrationToken='xxxxx Token xxxxx';

    var message={
        data:{
            title:'Go Notification',
            body:'Checking the app from node',
        },
        token:registrationToken
    };
    
    admin.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message',response);
        return res.json({status:true, msg:'Notification Sent'})
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error occurred while send the message',error);
        return res.json({status:false, msg:error})
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question, but correct me if I'm wrong since I'm a newbie too.
In your case 1, when app is not in foreground, It will call `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage`. The same situation is happenend in your case 2. When your app is terminated, it will call `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` instead of `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage`. I will give the link for the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage), maybe it will help you.

Comment: Exactly... When your app is terminated, it is not triggering FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage... i have tested using FlutterToast..

Comment: Did you terminated it (swipe it in the app list), or force stop it in app management?

Comment: swipe it in the app list

Comment: It should be showing though. Try to check whether backends is sending the notification correctly. Or maybe you can show us your payload?

Comment: Receiving the notification when app is terminated. Its navigating to particular screen when application is in foreground but not navigating to the particular screen instead its navigating to Home Screen when app is started from  terminated state.